# HashMap internally uses Node<K, V> array vs Hashtable internally uses Map.Entry<K, V> array, Why is this internal difference?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap, hashtable

`HashMap` internally uses `Node<K, V>` `array` vs `Hashtable` internally uses `Map.Entry<K, V>` `array`,  Why  this internal difference:

HashMap is using Node inner class with Map.Entry implementation.

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;

    Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
```

Hashtable is using Map.Entry.

```
private static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;

    protected Entry(int hash, K key, V value, Entry<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.key =  key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
```

seams to be both are same but they are different. 
Is there any specific reason to use `HashMap` is using `Node<K,V>` `array` instead of `Map.Entry<K,V>` `array` ?

Comment: As far as I see, the only difference between these classes is that they have different names. Note that `Entry<K, V>` is not the same as `Map.Entry<K, V>`.

Comment: The final sentence in this question seems to be asking whether there is a reason to use HashMap instead of Hashtable.  The answer is:  Always use HashMap, unless you are working with an API that requires a Hashtable instance, because Hashtable is a holdover from Java 1.0 that has mostly-useless per-method synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Both are using the interface `Map.Entry`. `HashTable`, which precedes `HashMap` provides a private class implementation of it, which is only accessible inside the `HashTable` class. Therefore, it would have been impossible to use it in `HashMap`.